# Using same SSH Key for both Bitbucket and Github

Tags: github, ssh, bitbucket

I'm using same email address on both platforms. Please let me know if it's possible, if not please guide me to best practice.

Thanks in advance.

I have successfully added the key to Bitbucket, all good here. When I tried to login GitHub via CLI (using `gh auth login`), I have faced this text:

```
HTTP 422: Validation Failed (https://api.github.com/user/keys)
key is already in use
```

Comment: don't know what the error is, but I would create different keys, it's very easy to create keys. Try creating the keys again see if that solves it

Comment: @Matthias It seems your suggestion will be wiser option.

Comment: What is the exact command you are running to log into GitHub? SSH keys have to be unique when connecting to github.com and the error message you are getting implies you are trying to add a key to a GitHub user and it's already being used by *another* GitHub user.

Comment: @tj-cappelletti  I'm using Github CLI to auth `gh auth login` and select `SSH` for auth method. I'm using that key for Bitbucket already, and I'd like to know is is possible to use same key for both Bitbucket and Github.

Comment: Yes, you can use the same key (provided it meets GitHub's security requirements) as you use in BitBucket. What I'm sayin is the error you are getting implies your SSH key is already in use in GitHub.

Comment: @tj-cappelletti Oh, how strange. I created the key right before using it to login GitHub so it's pretty much new. Is it that I need to use key first in GitHub then Bitbucket?

Answer (score 0):

While using a dedicated key pair for Github is the best practice, you can also use [`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login) with HTTPS and as a password a [GitHub PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) (Personal Access Token, typically, a classic one, scope `repos`)

```
echo ghp_xxx | auth login -p https --with-toke
```

[`gh auth status`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_status) and [`gh auth token`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_token) will confirm you are correctly logged in to GitHub, with the right identity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I'm doing already, and I have had separate SSH keys for each account, I just wanted to know if it's possible to `one key to rule them all`.

Comment: @onderbakirtas It might be technically possible, but not the best practice. Having separate key or token facilitates deprecating any of those in case of a compromised authentication.

Comment: Thank you for additional information. I'll go for that route. It was not necessary; I was curious if it's possible or not.